# Several data frames into matrices at once

Tags: r, loops, matrix, dataframe

I am new to R, so im sorry if it is not a good question.
I have several data frames called `matrix1`, `matrix2`, etc.
I want to use these 2 commands in a loop for all of them:

```
A1=as.matrix(matrix1)

B1=graph.adjacency(A1,mode="directed",weighted=NULL,diag=FALSE)
```

but I cannot figure out how to get the loop to change the names of the matrices.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get` to get a variable by its name.

e.g.

```
for (i in 1:n) {
    A1 = as.matrix(get(paste0('matrix', i)))
    B1 = graph.adjacency(A1,mode="directed",weighted=NULL,diag=FALSE) 
}
```

If you want to *store* the `B1`s, you could do so using (for example) a list:

```
Bs <- lapply(1:n, function (i) {
                A1 = ...
                B1 = ...
                return(B1)
             })
```

Then `Bs[[i]]` will contain the `B1` of matrix i.

And then, a further improvement - rather than manually naming all your matrices `matrix1`, `matrix2`, ... , `matrix10000` (particularly if you have a lot of them!), it would be better to store them in a list, e.g. `As[[i]]` is `matrix`i. (I can't give you specific code on how to do this, as it depends on where your matrices come from/how they are populated. e.g. you might `lapply(list_of_filenames, read.csv)` to read all the matrices from a list of file names).

Then you can:

```
Bs <- lapply(As, graph.adjacency, mode="directed", weighted=NULL, diag=FALSE)
```

without resorting to `get`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `assign()` to create matrices/data.frames in loops. Use `get()` when calling a numbered matrix/data.frame in your loop.

```
for (i in 1:n) {
  assign(paste0("A", i), unname(as.matrix(get(paste0("matrix", i)))))
  assign(paste0("B", i), graph.adjacency(get(paste0("A", i)),
                                         mode     = "directed",
                                         weighted = NULL,
                                         diag     = FALSE))
}
```

Comment: That was useful but now I have a new column  (rownames). I need to delete it from all matrices.

Comment: You can remove the rownames with `unname()` (see edited answer).  They actually aren't an extra column in the matrix however. Unless you mean you have another variable your dataframes that you need to remove?